# Circuit for averaging AC voltage

Tags: circuit-design, voltage-measurement

I made a rl multivibrator with square wave output. The ton and toff of rl changes with magnetic field around. Normally the wave is symmetrical but on passage of magnetic flux, the pulse width changes and the average voltage changes. I wanted to use this average voltage to measure current. Is there any circuit that averages voltage of square wave?

I know that I can use multimeter for measuring but I wanted to get a stable voltage that can be amplified by op-amp and finally be measured by multimeter.

In simple terms:
when t+ not equals t-, Vavg not equal zero.
And I want to amplify this voltage, sort of like dc offset but for both polarity.

I want to make myself clear again.
When you measure ac voltage with DMM in dc mode, you get a reading of 0v as average is zero. Now when you alter t+ and t- of signal you get net average voltage that's not zero on DMM in dc mode though actually the signal isn't a flat line. All I want is a simple circuit that can extract this net dc voltage as a stable voltage that I can amplify with op amp and again get a flat dc voltage that I can finally measure with DMM in dc mode.

Also I want the components to be passive if possible.

The circuit:
[image]

Comment: Please add a schematic

Comment: You probably want to measure the true RMS value of the waveform, not the average which will be zero if the squarewave goes both positive and negative.

Comment: no i really meant average voltage because as the t+ doesnt become equal to t- theres a vavg not equal zero.I want to amplify this voltage

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you want the DC component of your signal. Is that correct? If so, you want a low pass filter.

Comment: Or, if you want to examine them separately and then subtract, you'd need a *precision rectifier*, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier, to reduce the forward voltage drop of a diode.

Answer (score 1):

Fourier expansion of the signal would give you a constant offset (DC i.e. 0 Hz component) and a lot of sine waves with different frequencies. Since you want the DC component of the signal, you need to get rid of any other components with non-zero frequencies.

So a low-pass filter with a very low cut-off frequency (e.g. less than 0.5 Hz or maybe even lower) and maybe higher Q (requires higher order e.g. cascaded RC filters or LC filters) would work here. As the cut-off frequency gets lower and the order gets higher the result will have less ripple.

Below are examples to 2nd order low-pass filters:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEOzi2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The one to the left is the well-known LC filter. The one to the right is an active RC filter. If you select R1.C2 and R2.C3 products equal you'll get the same cut-off frequency and better filtering compared to a single RC filter. Note that if your signal has negative peaks the op-amp circuit will require dual supplies.

NOTE: If the signal is **not** periodic then the result will not be constant. So the average value you'll get will be the average value of a certain time frame of the signal.

---

Alternatively, there are digital methods, such as:

- Sampling & Processing: Sample the signal with a high enough sampling rate and process it (e.g. DFS - Discrete Fourier Series).
- ADC & timestamps: Measure the peaks (presumably constant), find rising and falling edges (to find pulse durations) with enough precision, and calculate the average by calculating the total area for a period and dividing the result by the period. This can be done with an MCU.

[image]

$$
\langle V \rangle = \frac{V_1 \ t_1 + (-V_2 \ (T-t_1))}{T}
$$

But since you need the resultant "voltage" you'll need a DAC with the digital methods.

> All I want is a simple circuit that can extract this net dc voltage as a stable voltage

The simplest way appears to be to use an LPF such as the circuits above.

Comment: Isnt there other methods?

Comment: @Saso see my edit.

Comment: Could you show me a opamp lpf circuit for dc component of 500hz square signal ?

Comment: @Saso I don't know your ripple requirements but as a starting point, you can take the second circuit shown in my answer above with R1 = R2 = 10k and C2 = C3 = 2.2 uF. This will give you a relatively harsh filtering above 7 Hz, hopefully enough to get a stable DC output with a low ripple (if you want lower, increase the values). The mid-band gain of the circuit is \$A_V=1+R2/R3\$ so if you select R2=R3 the result will be double the avg value of the signal. Note that the circuit will take some time to settle so you'll see a stable output after a few tens or maybe a few hundreds of milliseconds.

Comment: I want my ripple to be less than 20mv

Comment: @Saso try simulating the circuit with different values until you get enough ripple. The key is to keep the RC product equal for both RCs I mentioned above.

Comment: thanks for the circuit. I am trying it in lt spice but the ripple voltages are still in orders of 50mv

Comment: @Saso I tried the circuit for ±3V with a 25% duty cycle and I got 100 mVpp ripple. Increased the capacitor to 4.7u and the ripple is 50 mVpp. Note that this is "double" the output so if you take the half you'll get 25 mVpp. Also, I cascaded a copy of the same circuit and the ripple is now less than 1 mV. Note that this is "4 times" the output because each section has a gain of 2. So the actual ripple would be in orders of microvolts.

Comment: thanks , i tried your circuit cascading 2 of them in unity gain shorting out and inverting input and got 4mv ripple. i used r=60k and c=2.2u. Do u think it will be ok when I build the actual circuit?

Comment: However my circuit remained stable only after about 0.4s. Is it normal?

Comment: @Saso `in unity gain shorting out` don't short anything. If you want to get unity gain just use a voltage divider on the output to "reduce" the final output voltage.

Comment: I meant shorting out and inverting input. Won't it make a buffer?

Comment: @Saso that'll make it a buffer but also make a first order i.e. "softer" filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the low-cost 8-pin AD736 rms to DC converter with some success. Its input is limited to 200mv p-p. The DC output is filtered by user-selected capacitors so you select smoother output vs faster response.

The DC output (0 to + volts only) can be amplified as needed to drive an analog or digital meter.

Note that if capacitor filter values are reduced by 10 or more then you get a dynamic peak value that is the sum of positive and negative peaks.

Comment: The OP, it appears, wants to measure the DC component of the squarewave, not the true RMS value. Here's someone who really *does* want the average value.

Comment: @Transistor I  added a paragraph as to how the AD736 can output the sum of +/- peaks, but if the OP wants a peak-hold function, that is more hardware.

Comment: Thanks. I think s/he's just looking for an RC filter or an LC as described by @Rohic.

Comment: Thanks I think I will be using lpf as given by Rohic though it's a bit slow in getting stable. If there's other methods I am ok to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not too concerned about settling time you can do some initial testing with a simple passive filter like this:

[image]

Ripple is about 0.3mVp-p and it takes 2.5 seconds to settle to within 1mV and 3.5 seconds to where further change is minimal compared to the ripple.

The output resistance is 200kΩ so a 10MΩ DMM (R3) will present minimal loading.

For some reason that's not immediately clear to me this circuit has about a 12mV (positive) offset at the output in the simulation.